# Sitecore custom personalisation rules based on external API data

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

We have a requirement to create a personalisation rules based on data we get from external API.

An example of the implementation would be good as I could not find any for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Depend on the speed of your external API call and the reuse of the data and the cost of a call. there are multiple solutions.

Think about the geo ip, (with a provider) or the Mobile Device detector.
[Sitecore-Mobile-Device-Detector](https://github.com/adoprog/Sitecore-Mobile-Device-Detector)

A time ago on a User Group Meeting there was a Demo with external Fitbit data the,  This worked in the following way, get the data 1 time in a session and store it in the profile, in a custom analytics contact facet and create rules based on the contact facet. see the links in the slides from [how to personalize your sitecore site with fitbit data](http://www.slideshare.net/baslijten/mind-your-step-how-to-personalize-your-sitecore-site-with-fitbit-data-uploaded)